# Issues with SetContentView()

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I've been trying to achieve a secondary page for my basic starting goal of learning c# and xamarin, the code works for the first button and switches to the next page however when trying to switch back with another button it gives a "System.NullReferenceException" error message

Through trial I've tried to isolate some of the segments of the code to get one part working however when both are together I get the error message

Here's my code

```
var pageNext = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.pageNext);
        var pagePre = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.pagePre);
        pageNext.Click += (e, o) =>
        {
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Page_2);
        };
        pagePre.Click += (e, o) =>
        {
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        };
```

The error message I'm recieving:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Any advice would be useful as I'm quite new to this

Comment: as I forgot to write adding the second command sets the application into break mode

Comment: Don't post your code as an image. Instead, edit your post and paste it there. The same goes for the error message.